# How to detect key and mouse event on system any where using jquery or jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I know this is very difficult and may be impossible question but even though there is any solution please say me.

How we can detect the key and mouse event in our web application when client is working on other application and may be the browser in which our application is running is minimized.

Because my application is one type of timer in which i have to count idle time of the client on that machine by key and mouse event. it's dose not matter that client working on our application or other. important is that he must be work on that machine during my timer is running.

Comment: and you are trying achieve that in `html jquery`?

Comment: I want to do this but I don't know it's possible or not. I have done already this thing in my java desktop application now I want to implement same concept if possible in web application

Comment: if the user is in focus of your application, then you can get the events. or else you should write an application in native lang to keep track of what the user does.

Comment: yes, your are right that it's possible if user is in focus of my application. but I want to do this with user is in focus of anywhere. is it possible?

Comment: nope. what ever you are asking looks like a KEYLOGGER.

Comment: OK, Thanks for your timer and support @Cerlin Boss

Answer (score 2):

I don not know how you can achieve that in html/jquery, because it requires the browser to be on focus.
Try using node.js it can do stuff such as desktop applications.

Answer (score 1):

edit: as suggested by @HappyPatrick, you could prob do something like this in [ATOM SHELL](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell) or the like. You would just not create a window.

edit II -- I understand:

**1) interval stuff included because...**

> Because my application is one type of timer in which i have to count idle time of the client on that machine by key and mouse event.

***keep in mind that if you write a desktop client in js, you can still use this code.***

**2) Atom shell included because... it enables you to write desktop applications in js**

> How we can detect the key and mouse event in our web application when
>   client is working on other application and may be the browser in which
>   our application is running is minimized.

***if tracking user behavior outside browser, gui-less desktop app probably safe bet***

---

You could always do in a browser plug-in -- but only for in-browser behavior. Inject content scripts into pages/tabs of concern, attach event listeners to the documents which pass messages to a background script (e.g. like in chrome extension) to tracks idle status. plugin would obviously be different per browser, but jquery might look something like this:

```
var idleDuration = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {

    resetIdleTimer(60000, 9);

    $(this).on('mousemove keypress click', function() {
        idleDuration = 0;
        // 
        // handle these events here (creepy keylogging, etc)
        //
    });

    function resetIdleTimer(duration, maxCount) {

        // Increment idle counter every 1min. react after 10
        var idleInterval = setInterval(function() {
            idleDuration++;
            if (idleDuration > maxCount) { // 10 minute threshold reached 
                //
                // respond to idle
                //
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }, duration); // check at inteval of your pref
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you have not understand my question properly. I want to count keystroke and mouse move in any where on the system not only on browser or on my page. Anywhere even the browser is minimize. –

Comment: Sorry,but I can't understand that which you have suggested is work for only browser and tab or anywhere in system even browser is minimize

Comment: desktop application, bro. atom shell, to say it again. or node webkit, or brackets-shell....

Comment: OK thank you, i will try this and if face any difficulty then will contact you.

Comment: you could also help people that help you by marking answers as upvoted or correct.

Comment: yes I can do it but first of all I must have to verify that answer by implementing in application.

Answer (score 1):

To detect the activity of the user you can utilize the onmousemove  Event in javascript

It executes when the mouse pointer is over a particular div in the page in the browser.

If you want it to record the user activity on the complete page body content, you can use it in this fashion
 `<body onmousemove = "recordactivity(event)">` 
Else 
If you want it to record end to end of your page, you can attach it in your html tag itself 
`<html onmousemove = "recordactivity(event)">`

You can get the coordinates of the page using the clientX and clientY
and track the user  mouse pointer location.

Comment: I think you have not understand my question properly. I want to count keystroke and mouse move in any where on the system not only on browser or on my page. Anywhere even the browser is minimize.